# docker-compose connection refused 5432

Tags: docker

Can you help? Although 5432 is on, it won't connect.
my docker compose

```
  ecommerce:
    image: ecommerce
    ports:
      - "8089:8089"
    volumes:
      - $HOME/app:/var/app
    links:
      - "logstash:logstash"
    depends_on:
      - kibana
      - postgresql

  postgresql:
    image: postgres:10.4
    volumes:
      - ./postgresql/:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=123456
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=kullanat
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
```

error:
Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.

i couldn't solve this error

properties :

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://postgresql:5432/kullanat
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=123456
spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.validation.mode = none
```

github:
https://github.com/furkannzmnn/ecommerce/blob/master/src/main/resources/docker-compose.yml

pg_hba.conf

[image]

Comment: I added a picture to the description.

Comment: thank you for the answer but i don't know how to fix it can you help?

Comment: don't work :/..

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/ does it help?

Comment: Sorry, what you actually need to change is the `listen_address` in `postgresql.conf`. Set it to `listen_address='*'` and it should work. Mixed those two configs up again, sorry.

Comment: already so :( ...

Comment: The `localhost` in the error message doesn't match the `spring.datasource.url=postgres` host name in the configuration; are you sure that configuration is getting applied?  What should the picture show, and if it's a configuration file of some sort, would it be clearer to replace it with the text of the config file (I don't think you can use a PNG image file to configure PostgreSQL)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Database configuration

What you need to do is change the `listen_address` in `postgresql.conf` to `'*'`.

Here the relevant section of the `postgresql.conf` file. You will have to restart the DB service to be sure the changes take affect.

```
# -----------------------------
# PostgreSQL configuration file
# -----------------------------
#
# lots of configuration values here...

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# CONNECTIONS AND AUTHENTICATION
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# - Connection Settings -

listen_addresses = '*'
                    # comma-separated list of addresses;
                    # defaults to 'localhost'; use '*' for all
                    # (change requires restart)
#port = 5432                # (change requires restart)
#max_connections = 100          # (change requires restart)
#superuser_reserved_connections = 3 # (change requires restart)


# lots of configuration values here...


#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# CUSTOMIZED OPTIONS
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Add settings for extensions here
```

You should probably check out the [documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres) for that container on DockerHub. Especially the part where it says `Database configuration`.

### Docker-compose

For docker container to "talk" to each other and use Docker's service discovery they must be in the same user-defined network. See the [networking tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-standalone/) for more details.

In a docker compose file you can create this network using `networks` and attach the containers that are supposed to communicate with each other to that network.

```yaml
services:
  # there are other services defined here as well it seems, add them here
  # remove links as they are deprecated and use networks instead
  ecommerce:
    image: ecommerce
    # assign a name to this container
    container_name: ecommerce
    ports:
      - "8089:8089"
    volumes:
      - $HOME/app:/var/app
    # connect this container to the user-defined network
    networks:
      - my-network
    links:
      - "logstash:logstash" # dont use links anymore, use networks instead
    depends_on:
      - kibana
      - postgresql

  postgresql:
    image: postgres:10.4
    # assign a name to this container
    container_name: postgresql
    volumes:
      - ./postgresql/:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
     # connect this container to the user-defined network my-network
    networks:
      - my-network
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=123456
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=kullanat
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"

# declare the network ressource
# this will allow you to use service discovery and address a container by its name from within the network
networks:
  my-network
```

Now the containers can address other containers in the network using their container name as a hostname. As your Postgres container is called `postgresql` using above docker-compose you need to configure your application to connect to `postgresql:5432` so a connection can be established.

Comment: don't work bro.. I was try

Comment: You need to narrow down you problem then. Can you connect to you postgres instance using `psql` from your host? You need to find out your containers IP address first using `docker inspect` then try `psql -U postgres -h 172.2.0.1 -p 5432 -d kullanat` (assuming the container's IP is `172.2.0.1`). Then enter the password when prompted. If this works the issue is in your application configuration.

Comment: output : psql: error: connection to server at "172.2.0.1", port 5432 failed: Connection refused
        Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?

Comment: Ok and you have checked that `172.2.0.1` is the IP address of your container? I've just picked a random IP address but you need to use the one your container has. You may also use `nmap -p 5432 <container-ip-address>` to check if the port is actually open.

Comment: okey, now output : psql (14.2 (Debian 14.2-1.pgdg110+1))

Comment: ı connected, what is skip next ?

Comment: This means your database configuration works just fine, now you just need to configure the containers correctly so they can communicate with each other. See my remarks on the `docker-compose.yaml` file in my post.

Comment: I really can't solve this problem. It still gives connection refused error. localhost:5432 connection refused

Comment: Don't connect to localhost. There is no database server running on localhost, so you can't connect to it. You could only connect to localhost from within the Postgres container, which you are not (a container has its own localhost, that is not the host's localhost). You need to use `postgresql:5432` when you want to connect to the database from **within** your network `my-network`. If you are trying to connect from the outside you would need to use the container's IP address instead, same way as you did with `psql` because `psql` was used on the host **outside** the network `my-network`.

Comment: Ok. So that's Java telling you the host is unknown. Is your application already running in a container and connected to the network `my-network`? It has to be. And is your postgres container actually named `postgresql` and also up and running and connected to the `my-network` network? All those things have to be, otherwise it won't work. You can check container names and status using `docker ps -a`. Use `docker inspect <container-name>` and see `"Networks"` to check which networks a container is connected to.

Comment: Glad to hear that :D That was hard work :D