# psycopg2.OperationalError: connection to server at "db" (172.20.0.3), port 5432 failed: Connection refused

Tags: python, postgresql, docker, devops

I have this **docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: example
      POSTGRES_DB: mydatabase
    volumes:
      - ./init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
  app:
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: postgresql://postgres:example@db:5432/mydatabase
```

This Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8    
WORKDIR /app    
COPY requirements.txt .    
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt    
COPY . .    
CMD ["python", "./app.py"]
```

And this app.py

```
    conn = psycopg2.connect(
    host="db",
    database="mydatabase",
    user="postgres",
    password="example",
    port="5432"
)

cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT version();")
print(cur.fetchone())
```

When I enter the command `docker-compose up --build` I execute everything  and this error appears: `psycopg2.OperationalError: connection to server in "db" (172.20. 0.3), port 5432 failed: connection refused`

Does anyone know why it didn't connect?

Comment: Sometimes the database can take some time to set up, and the application can start first, which could lead to errors like this.  You're running `docker-compose up` without a `-d` option.  Are there database initialization messages after the application error?  If you run `docker-compose up -d` twice, does it work the second time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the database and your app in a [user-defined bridge network](https://docs.docker.com/network/drivers/bridge/#differences-between-user-defined-bridges-and-the-default-bridge) so they both reside in the same network and can actually communicate with each other.

When they are both in the same user-defined bridge, you can use the container names as host names and Docker will resolve those to the actual IP addresses (DNS resolution) to make the communication possible. So be sure to assign container names for your convenience.

Additionally you also need to tell the Postgres container to expose port `5432` to the outside world (i. e. to the user-defined network) otherwise you won't be able to connect.

These are the basics of docker networking. Be sure to check the [Docker docs on networking](https://docs.docker.com/network/) to get a more detailed understanding.

Untested, but should work:

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    container_name: db # this will become available as DNS name
    networks: # connect to app network
      - app
    ports:
      - "5432" # expose port 5432 on the container
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: example
      POSTGRES_DB: mydatabase
    volumes:
      - ./init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
  app:
    build: .
    networks: # connect to app network
      - app
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: postgresql://postgres:example@db:5432/mydatabase # we can now use @db here this this DNS name will be created by docker
networks:
  app: # create app network
```

Depending on your Postgres configuration Postgres might still refuse to let any IP address connect, so be sure to adjust the `listen_addresses = '*'`.

For more details on how to configure the Postgres container image check the documentation of the [Postgres container image](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres) (especially the section on *Database Configuration*) or [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71551209/17487348) and of course the [Postgres docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-connection.html).

### Edit

As [David Maze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10008173/david-maze) mentioned in the comment, it's not necessary to actually create the user-defined bridge since docker desktop creates a default network for you and attaches the created containers to that network.

From the [Docker Docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/):

> By default Compose sets up a single network for your app. Each container for a service joins the default network and is both reachable by other containers on that network, and discoverable by the service's name.

That being said, creating and assigning the network manually (i. e. by specifying in in the docker compose file) is not wrong and gives you a bit more control on who can communicate with whom especially if you have a more complex setup with multiple services involved (e.g. it would make sense if you use a [Database per service pattern in microservices](https://microservices.io/patterns/data/database-per-service.html)).

Comment: This is unnecessary.  Compose automatically creates a network named `default` on its own, and attaches containers to it; most applications do not need `networks:` at all.  Also see [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation for more details on this setup.

Comment: Thanks for the addition @David Maze, I was not aware that was the case. I have added a corresponding remark to my answer.